# How to Inject dependencies in a Unity IoC container for SignalR hub?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, unity-container

I have an application that is written with c# on the top of the ASP.NET MVC 5 Framework. I implemented [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) into my project. Now, I am trying to inject dependencies objects into my [SignalR Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc).

I created a class called `UnityHubActivator`

My class looks like this

```
public class UnityHubActivator : IHubActivator
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityHubActivator(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHub Create(HubDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        return (IHub)_container.Resolve(descriptor.HubType);
    }
}
```

Then in my `UnityConfig` class I added the following to my `RegisterTypes` method

```
var unityHubActivator = new UnityHubActivator(container);

container.RegisterInstance<IHubActivator>(unityHubActivator);
```

My hub looks like this

```
[Authorize]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public ChatHub(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        : base()
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

}
```

But when I run the hub, the constructor never get called and the connection never takes place.

How can I correctly use `Unity` framework to inject dependencies into my hub?

**UPDATED**

I tried to created a custom container like so

```
public class UnitySignalRDependencyResolver: DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    protected IUnityContainer Container;
    private bool IsDisposed = false;

    public UnitySignalRDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        Container = container.CreateChildContainer();
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (Container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
        {
            return Container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }

        return base.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (Container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
        {
            return Container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }

        return base.GetServices(serviceType);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        if(IsDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(disposing)
        {
            Container.Dispose();
        }

        IsDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Then here is how I configured the hub in the Startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }
    public Startup(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            var resolver = new UnitySignalRDependencyResolver(Container);

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                Resolver = resolver
            };

            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
}
```

But still now working... the hub constructor never get called.

Here is how I am calling my hub from the client

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>

$(function () {
    // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
    var app = $.connection.chatHub;
    console.log('Getting things ready....');

    app.client.outOfTasks = function () {
        console.log('Nothing to do here')
    };

    app.client.logError = function (message) {
        console.log(message)
    };

    app.client.logNote = function (message) {
        console.log(message)
    };

    app.client.assignTask = function (taskId) {
        app.server.taskReceived();
        console.log('task received!!!' + taskId);

    };

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log('Connection Started....');
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Documentation Reference [Dependency Injection in SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UnitySignalRDependencyResolver` appears accurate for that container.

Taken from the official documentation,

[Dependency Injection in SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)

try the following example for configuring *Startup*

```
public class Startup{    
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        IUnityContainer container = GetContainer(); 

        var resolver = new UnitySignalRDependencyResolver(container);

        var config = new HubConfiguration {
            Resolver = resolver
        };      
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr", config);
    }

    IUnityContainer GetContainer() {
        //...call the unity config related code.
        var container = UnityConfig.Container;
        //...any other code to populate container.

        return container;
    }
}
```

Make sure to register the necessary objects, including the hub (`ChatHub`) with the container as the container needs to know the object graph in order to resolve the necessary dependencies.

Comment: Looking into this, your on the right track here. I had to remove the constructor from the Startup class and use `UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer()`. I get no errors but the constructor of the hub never get called.

Comment: @MikeA Are you making any connections from the client?

Comment: yes outsource. I just updated my question with the JS code used to call the client. What is weird is that I get the following messages in the console.. `Getting things ready...` then `Connection Started...` which sounds like the connection is established but there is no more communication and the constructor is never called.

Comment: @MikeA I am not seeing an example of an action in the hub that is being called from the client. update example. Also for debugging purposes remove Authorize attribute.

Comment: The communication starts from the server. when the client connect, I run  some code in the hub which calls this `Clients.User(GetIdentity.Name).assignTask(TaskId.Value)` this sends the client a message using the `assignTask` function. When that is received, the client send a confirmation message using the `app.server.taskReceived();` but since the hub constructor or even the `OnConnected` method, the server never send a signal

Comment: Update the question with a [mcve] so that I can at least try to reproduce the problem. The hub in the question is not a true representation of the actual hub based on you recent comment.

Comment: @MikeA wait, did you register the hub with the container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166003/discussion-between-mike-a-and-nkosi).