# signalr hubs created but server OnConnected() not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

using Signalr version 2.2.2 installed from nuget. 
as startup code

```
 public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    { 
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

and Hub.cs file is

```
 public class MyChatHub : Hub
    {
        private IUserService _userService;
        private IMessageService _messageService; 
        public MyChatHub(IUserService userService,IMessageService messageService)
        {
            _messageService = messageService;
            _userService = userService;
        }
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            var userID = Context.QueryString["UserId"];
            if (userID != null)
            {
                Guid uId = Guid.Parse(userID);
                _userService.SaveUserOnlineStatus(new OnlineUsers { UserId = uId, ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId, IsOnline = true });
                //RefreshOnlineUsers(uId);
            }
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
```

my js file is

```
var chat = $.connection.myChatHub;

$.connection.hub.start();
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

1. I Can see the signalr/hubs created with defined functions
   [image]
2. I can see the network start and connection id
   [image]
   My Issue : 
   server and client not communicated. new project is working fine. 
   [image]

Comment: Maybe since it is a task, you should override `OnConnectedAsync`?

Comment: it throw error. but my sample project working with same function Hub not defined OnConnectedAsync. OnConncted also aync function.

Comment: Have you got code to setup the dependencies?.IUserService and IMessageService

Comment: @EddDotNet Yes. using Unity i did.

Comment: @SaravananArunagiri Sorry I should have been more specifc. Have you got it setup like is shown here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49038509/947569
I recently had a similar issue that was down to not setting up the dependencies with SignalR

Comment: @EddDotNet Yeah your right. using dependencies resolver now i can see that connected. FYI,http://www.tomdupont.net/2014/01/dependency-injection-with-signalr-and.html.